# Fetching json data from server-side php file with angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using plain javascript  to fetch data from php scripts server-side but I'd like to try it out using angular.

This code fetches a php file that in turn queries a database (simple select with filter, etc) and returns a json file to be used by the script and then displayed.

Is there a simple way of doing this with angular?

This is the script as it is now

```
fetch('service/select.php')
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
    //do something with the data
});
```

and this is the php file it fetches:

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');
    mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");
    $rs = mysqli_query($con, "select * from names");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
        $res[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

(I know the php file is vulnerable to sql injection, its just an example file to quickly query data, not used in production)

Comment: The same way, just using httpClient.

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y7xovz)  `HTTPClient` module is your need

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
};
@Injectable()
export class DataService{
    constructor(private http:HttpClient){  }
    
    Post(url:string,body:any): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.post<any>(url, body, httpOptions).pipe( retry(1), catchError(this.handleError) );
    }
    Get(url:string): Observable<any>{
        return this.http .get<any>(url, httpOptions).pipe( retry(1), catchError(this.handleError) );
    }
    private handleError(error: any){
        let body = error.json();     
        return body || {};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) API to do HTTP requests. The response type of this API is **Observable** type of RxJS which has lots of built-in methods to
process your data.

You can do your HTTP request code as following in the angular way instead of **fetch** API.

```js
const url = 'service/select.php';
const hdrs = new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': accept ? accept : 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
this.http.get(url, { headers: hdrs, observe: 'body', responseType: 'json'})
.subscribe(
  data => // do whatever you want to do your data
  err => // get the error response here
);
```